# No Java installation was detected while sbt update

Tags: java, sbt

Hi was trying to run sbt update comand in cygwin and i get the error "No java installation was detected" even tough i have java installed .

My java in present in C:\Program Files\Java

My sbt is installed in C:\Program Files(x86)\sbt

I found one similar question over here in StackOverflow but i couldnt resolve it.

Any help?

Thanks ,
Vishesh

Comment: Tru ```sudo``` or doing it via root user. Sometimes brew or another install utility installs sbt as root .

Answer (score 1):

Set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to where your JDK is
For eg:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- Go to the `Control Panel`
- Select the `System` icon
- In the left column select `Advanced System Settings`
- In the tabs select `Advanced` and then `Environmental Variables...`
- In the lower part click `New` and set

Variable Name: `JAVA_HOME`
Variable Value: `C:\Program Files\Java\<JAVA_FOLDER>`

Change the `<JAVA_FOLDER>` with the one you're using

Comment: To skip steps 1 and 2, I just use Start Menu's search functionality. It usual the first one selected when I type `edit s`(ystem)

Comment: JDK location is in PATH, and JAVA_HOME is set correctly. Problem persists. Also DOS utility app findstr.exe is found. It appear SBT shell ignores the PATH env variable